# converting std::string to double with negative values results in zero or throws an exception

Tags: c++

### Context

A number is read from an input file as a `std::string` and converted into a `double`.

### My solution

I tried a variety of approaches based on what I could find on the web:

```
  std::string str = "­‐12.5799";
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
  double d;
  std::stringstream(str) >> d;
  std::cout << d << std::endl;
  std::cout << atof(str.c_str()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << stod(str) << std::endl;
```

### Problem

It seems to work well when positive number are read from the file, but results in strange errors and exceptions when there is a sign "-" at the beginning of the `std::string`.

Output:

```
‐12.5799
0
0
stod
```

I'm obviously missing something?

Comment: What makes you think the `-` is relevant? Do you get the expected results for positive values?

Comment: This symbol `"­‐"` is not a negative sign it's a hyphen (the real negative sign looks similar `"-"`, but it's a different character)

Comment: Son of a gun. I HATE it when that happens.

Comment: sorry, my brain just exploded. I'm gonna cry a bit, and come back. 
How can I even know that his is not a negative sign ? :'(

Comment: @ArnaudBecheler By pasting it into https://babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html

Comment: I had to dump it into hex (AD 2D 31 32 2E 35 37 39 39) to see there was an extra byte there. Make no mistake this is a nasty thing to spot. Another trick is to save the file as ASCII and see if there ae any complaints.

Comment: My ol' copy of MultiEdit from '98 hates unicode and displays "­--12.5799"

Comment: The output you got from `stod` is interesting though. Maybe it's just poorly-formatted unhandled exception text

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings yes, it was a bad exception handling, it should be something like: `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::invalid_argument'
  what():  stod
Aborted (core dumped)`

Comment: I vaguely recall encountering some impl that just dumps `what()` without any adornment. Can't remember what it was, but it doesn't matter :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is not an ordinary ASCII hyphen/minus character.

It is instead the following sequence of codepoints:

- U+00AD : [SOFT HYPHEN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_hyphen) [SHY] {discretionary hyphen}
- U+2010 : HYPHEN

Your parsing attempts are therefore failing.

When in doubt, copy/paste your text into a hex editor, or an online tool such as https://babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html.

Always consider this as a debugging step if you encounter some mysterious problem with characters such as hyphens ([which are accompanied by a myriad of visually-similar yet distinct characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen#Unicode)).

So-called "smart" quotes are another good example of characters far less innocent than they claim to be.

Comment: It's U+2010, actually.  Everybody needs a better text editor :)

Comment: The way this year's turned out you'd think it was U+2020.

Comment: @HansPassant So it is. That'll teach me to read only one line of output 

Comment: Your mishap is a lot more interesting than the OP's.  Embellish, please.

Comment: @HansPassant There's not much to tell; I literally just [only read one line of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TL6N.png)